# Examples of Thread Use in Open Source Applications

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have read the documentation on pthreads and OpenMP and I understand them.  I have read through the examples as well as implemented small parts of program using them.  Are there good examples of production open source applications written in C++ which also employ threads extensively?

Comment: MPI and pthreads have very different uses.

Comment: That was a typo.  I meant OpenMP.  When I last read about this subject, I was also reading about MPI for which there is an OpenMPI, and which causes me confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two that I can think of off the top of my head are [LuxRender](http://www.luxrender.net/en_GB/index) and [Blender](http://www.blender.org/).

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Blender has the added benefit of good architecture documentation.

Answer (score 0):

why not look at Threading Building Blocks? To me it's the best of both worlds - algo-level threading like in OpenMP and low-level threading and control through std::thread and observers/schedulers. Cross-platform, free, comes with great documentation and a full set of examples.

Comment: I know that they are out there, but mostly I work on SPARCs.  For this question, I am interested in seeing examples of how people have integrated the threads-as-concurrency paradigm with C++ in a production application.

Comment: They used to discuss a port of TBB to SPARC Solaris somewhere [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=63880), take a look, maybe it'll help. What do you mean by "threads-as-concurrency paradigm", just curious. Thanks.